# dotnet new console not working [Ubuntu 23.04]

Tags: visual-studio-code, dotnet, sdk

I am trying to install .NET SDK to use with VS Code.

When I type `dotnet new console` the following is returned:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'new' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Typing `dotnet --version` also returns the error above.

On the other hand `dotnet --version` does not list anything.

I followed various sites to try to install the sdk [How to Install .NET Core (dotnet) on Ubuntu 22.04](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-dotnet-core-on-ubuntu-22-04/) and [C#(Dotnet) Setup in Ubuntu with VSCode](https://chrisdevcode.hashnode.dev/cdotnet-setup-in-ubuntu-with-vscode) without success.

---

Update: I followed the page at [Install .NET SDK or .NET Runtime on Ubuntu 23.04](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-2304).  Below is the output of the commands on this site:

```
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ dotnet --list-sdks
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
--2023-05-25 17:55:54--  https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
Resolving dot.net (dot.net)... 20.81.111.85, 20.53.203.50, 20.112.52.29, ...
Connecting to dot.net (dot.net)|20.81.111.85|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/scripts/v1/dotnet-install.sh [following]
--2023-05-25 17:55:54--  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/scripts/v1/dotnet-install.sh
Resolving dotnet.microsoft.com (dotnet.microsoft.com)... 13.107.238.64, 13.107.237.64, 2620:1ec:4f:1::64, ...
Connecting to dotnet.microsoft.com (dotnet.microsoft.com)|13.107.238.64|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Cookie coming from dotnet.microsoft.com attempted to set domain to dotnetwebsite.azurewebsites.net
Cookie coming from dotnet.microsoft.com attempted to set domain to dotnetwebsite.azurewebsites.net
Length: 58824 (57K) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘dotnet-install.sh’

dotnet-install.sh     100%[=========================>]  57.45K  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s   

2023-05-25 17:55:54 (5.56 MB/s) - ‘dotnet-install.sh’ saved [58824/58824]

hadmin@hp-linux:~$ sudo chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest
dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK with version '6.0.408' is already installed.
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest --runtime aspnetcore
dotnet-install: ASP.NET Core Runtime with version '6.0.16' is already installed.
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ ./dotnet-install.sh --channel 7.0
dotnet-install: Attempting to download using aka.ms link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/7.0.302/dotnet-sdk-7.0.302-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/7.0.302/dotnet-sdk-7.0.302-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Installed version is 7.0.302
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/home/hadmin/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ dotnet --list-sdks
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
hadmin@hp-linux:~$
```

Update following comment from @Khalid

```
hadmin@hp-linux:~$ env | grep DOTNET_ROOT
DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/lib/dotnet

hadmin@hp-linux:~$ ls /usr/lib/dotnet/
dotnet  host  LICENSE.txt  packs  shared  ThirdPartyNotices.txt

hadmin@hp-linux:~$ ls $HOME/.dotnet/
corefx  host         packs  sdk-manifests  templates
dotnet  LICENSE.txt  sdk    shared         ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

The environment variable is pointing to the wrong directory.

I would like to clean the installation including the multiple installations and set the environment variable to point to the correct folder.

How can I do that please (which file holds the .NET environment variables)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem was explained here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/32804. To quickly summarize, Canonical recently released the official dotnet package, removing MS source.list (or commenting out `deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/23.04/prod lunar main` ) and installing `dotnet*` solves the problem:

```shell
$ sudo apt-get purge dotnet-sdk-7.0
$ sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list && sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y dotnet7
$ dotnet --info
.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.110 [/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk]
```

If you still want to use `dotnet-sdk-7.0` sourced from `packages.microsoft.com`, the priority of the package needs to be increased (haven't tried this solution myself, but it makes sense):

```bash
echo -e "Package: *\nPin: origin packages.microsoft.com\nPin-Priority: 1001" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/dotnet
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing the SDKs. You get no results when you run `dotnet --list-sdks`, which hints that you're only installing the runtimes.

I recommend installing the SDKs using the `install.sh` file on https://dot.net and then ensuring the install directories are in your path. Which it seems you are doing.

You might need to restart your terminal and try again. Sometimes the `.bashrc` isn't reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to fix this was by using the `install.sh` script from https://dot.net, which install dotnet as a user scoped.

The default Canonical was not the latest version and the Microsoft was not installing the SDK (at least not registering the SDK path)